# How do I create a message-id for email in python?

Tags: python, email, header, rfc2822

I would like to add a unique [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html) compliant `Message-ID` header to a message created using [Python's built in `email` library](https://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html). How would I got about doing this? Is there a way within the library itself?

Comment: This should never have been closed as off-topic. It was perfectly clear exactly what the question was. The request for a library recommendation could've easily been edited out or ignored, especially since the answer is in the Python standard library itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might help:

```
from email.utils import make_msgid 
make_msgid()
```

This is described here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.make_msgid

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.make_msgid

Comment: Quick and helpful. Thanks.